# Javascript useragent grid?

Tags: javascript, cross-platform, user-agent

Does anyone know of an existing browser/OS useragent string grid? It's hard to test, and I would really like a broad sampling of useragent strings, if possible. If no such grid exists, mind posting your useragent string?

Given the idiosyncrocies of the browser/operating system combinations, this information is essential for successful web development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a grid but, [this site](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) seems pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest against relying on user-agent strings in any kind of JS app. You will get nothing but problems. Browsers have new versions, some change spoof the user-agent string etc.

A good example was that various sites broke when Opera 10 was released, because they were sniffing the user agent string and read 10 as 1.

Instead, you should use feature detection - test if the browser supports what you're trying to do.

There is really no good reason to sniff the user agent string, other than collecting usage statistics.

Comment: Absolutely -- UA sniffing is the death knell to future compatibilty (i know sites that broke in Safari 2.0.4, and Safari 4 because they interpreted "4" as meaning Netscape 4, so tried to use layers...)

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this site](http://browsers.garykeith.com/) useful.

In particular, in the downloads section, there is a massive [CSV file](http://browsers.garykeith.com/stream.asp?BrowsCapCSV) with over 3000 user agent strings, and which browsers they correspond to.